# $\inf$ and $\sup$ of $K = \bigg\{ \frac{m}{n}+\frac{4n}{m} : m,n \in \mathbb N\bigg\}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

**Exercise :**

> Consider the set :
>   $$K = \bigg\{ \frac{m}{n}+\frac{4n}{m} : m,n \in \mathbb N\bigg\}$$
>   Find $\inf K$ and $\sup K$.

**Attempt :**

$$\frac{m}{n}+\frac{4n}{m} = \frac{m^2 + 4n^2}{mn}$$

Now, it is :

$$\frac{m^2 + 4n^2}{mn} \geq 4 \Leftrightarrow (2n-m)^2 \geq 0$$

which holds $\forall \; n,m \in \mathbb N$. Also, it is :

$$\frac{m^2 + 4n^2}{mn} = 4 \Leftrightarrow m=2n$$

Thus $\exists \; n,m \in \mathbb N : \frac{m^2 + 4n^2}{mn} = 4$, thus $\inf K = 4$.

**How should I proceed on finding $\sup K$ now ?**

Comment: Try putting $n=1$.

Comment: @JohnMa I would yield $$m + \frac{4}{m}$$ Now, how would I continue though ? By taking some limits ?

Comment: What is $\sup_m \{ m + \frac{4}{m}\}$ (note the second term is small)

Comment: @JohnMa Well the second term vanishes and then it's only $m$, thus goes to infinity ?

Comment: Yes, $\sup K$ does not exists.

Comment: @JohnMa Perfect ! How am I sure that this works though, plugging in $n=1$ I mean ? (I am just asking to learn, not doubting the solution)

Comment: Okay I think I will just write an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that 
$$
K = \bigg\{ \frac{m}{n}+4\frac{1}{\frac{m}{n}} : m,n \in \mathbb N\bigg\}
$$
The rational numbers are dense in $\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$. Then the $\inf K$ and $\sup K$ coincide with the $\min f(x)$ and $\max f(x)$ for 
$$
f(x)=x+4\cdot \frac{1}{x}
$$

Comment: But here $m , n \in N$... How do you find the supremum?@MathOverview

Answer (score 2):

A note: if they gave you $$ r + \frac{3}{r}  $$
with rational $r > 0,$ there would still be an infimum by switching to $$ x + \frac{3}{x}$$ for positive real $x,$ taking the derivative $1 - \frac{3}{x^2},$ then plugging back $x = \sqrt 3$ giving $2 \sqrt 3.$

However, it is not possible to achieve this with rational $r,$ so there is an infimum that is not attained.  Officially, no minimum.

The original problem works because $4$ is a square

Answer (score 1):

One can actually show that a supremum does not exists: if $\sup K$ does exists, call this $L$. Then the Archimedian property tells us that $L < m$ for some $m\in \mathbb N$. Then $L < m + \frac{4}{m}$. But $m + \frac{4}{m}$ is in $K$ (by choosing $n=1$). But this is impossible as $L$ is an upper bound of $K$.

Thus $\sup K$ does not exists.